# can I find input elements based on their click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the id's input elements based on their click functions

```
   <div>
    <div class="input-group">
     <span>#</span>
     <input id="input1" onclick="foo1()"/>
    </div>
      <input id="input2">
   </div>

   <div>
    <div class="input-group">
     <span>#</span>
     <input id="input3" onclick="foo2()"/>
    </div>
      <input id="input4">
   </div>

   <div>
    <div class="input-group">
     <span>#</span>
     <input id="input5" onclick="foo1()"/>
    </div>
      <input id="input6">
   </div>
```

I m looking a jquery/javascript that returns id's of input which has click function "foo1"

Comment: Just a side comment that it's really a lot better to find things via id's or class names so if you control the HTML, I'd suggest you set up the class names or id values so you can use them to find what you want.

Answer (score 7):

It's an attribute, so you can use the attributes selector (there's also attribute [starts with, ends with, contains](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) etc)

```
$('input[onclick="foo1()"]')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/SZy9m/)